# Cannot find module ./environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I didn't use any `require` or anything to do with `environment` in my code, so I don't know how to fix this.

I tried `npm install environment`, which results in an error.

```
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
```

I think this was caused by `const {func} = require('../../server.js');`  and `module.exports = {func};` , to export/import my variables, and when I remove it, the environment error isn't there (but I need this code.)

`public/server.js`

```js
const func = {
    myId: "690173341104865310", 
    sampleFunction: function (text, moreText) {
        return `<@\$authorID> I'm returning ${text} and ${moreText} from func.sampleFunction`
    },
}
module.exports = {func};
```

`public/_commands/_utility/eval.js`

```js
const {func} = require('../../server.js'); 
module.exports = {
    name: "eval",
    code: `
        $eval[$message]
        $onlyIf[$userID[$username]==${func.myId}]
        `
  };
```

Also, this is my `package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "wink",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node public/server.js"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.x"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/node-pre-gyp": "^0.2.0",
        "@discordjs/opus": "^0.4.0",
        "dbd.db": "^1.3.14",
        "dbd.js": "^2.2.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "python": "0.0.4"
    },
    "prettier": {
        "trailingComma": "es5",
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "semi": false,
        "singleQuote": false
    }
}
```